# HTML element moving to next line

Tags: html, css

I am writing a CSS and I need to use a float to place an element in the top-left corner. I want the element to not move when the page resizes. However, when I resize the page the element (a navigation header for my webpage) moves to the next line and I want to stay in its position. I have tried positioning it as fixed but it needs to scroll with the whole page.

```css
#navigation {
   float: right;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: blue;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
#navigation a{
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Stores</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Buy</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Shop</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Information</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: there are confusing signals in your question. _"I need to use a float to place an element in the top-left corner"_ .. but you used `float: right`. _"when I resize the page the element moves to the next line"_ it's not true because you set a fixed width

Comment: if you need an element to stay in a specific position then a non-static position would be more appropriate such as `sticky`, `fixed` or `absolute`